# MySQL select group by clause not working

Tags: mysql

I am using

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM chat GROUP BY sender");
```

According to table below I should get 1 row where I have only one sender and I have total message of 3 rows if I am 'b'

Table chat

```
sender    destination   message
| a |     | b        |  |  ..  |
| b |     | a        |  |  ..  |
| a |     | b        |  |      |
| a |     | b        |  |      |
| b |     | a        |  |      |
```

I get this error message

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'chat.chat.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Do you want to concatenate all answers from one sender, regardless of destination? What if there are hundreds of answers, or long answers that would be to long for your message variable to handle?

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<s>You need to use grouped column in select.</s>  (Editor's strike out, this is an untrue statement which is disproved by editor's answer.)

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT sender FROM chat GROUP BY sender");
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` does not deny the ability to use a wildcard (`*`) in the `SELECT` clause, nor require that the `GROUP BY` column(s) are included in the `SELECT` clause.

This makes [mkysoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2847159/mkysoft)'s assertion that:

> You need to use grouped column in select.

**completely wrong** and **irresponsibly/terribly misleading** to SO readers.

I will demonstrate a few simple queries using the following table structure & data:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `chat` (
>   `sender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
>   `destination` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
>   `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> INSERT INTO `chat` (`sender`, `destination`, `message`) VALUES
> ('a', 'b', 'm1'),
> ('b', 'a', 'm2'),
> ('a', 'b', 'm3'),
> ('a', 'b', 'm4'),
> ('b', 'a', 'm5');
> ```

Using this query to get all columns from all rows with unique `sender`-`destination` pairs:

```
SELECT * FROM `chat` GROUP BY `sender`,`destination`
```

Output will be:

```
sender    destination    message
a         b              m1
b         a              m2
```

---

Using this query to get the `destination` column from rows with unique `senders`:

```
SELECT `destination` FROM `chat` GROUP BY `sender`
```

Output will be:

```
destination
b
a
```

---

Using this query to get all columns from all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `chat`
```

Output will be:

```
sender    destination    message
a         b              m1
b         a              m2
a         b              m3
a         b              m4
b         a              m5
```

---

Using this query to get all three columns from all rows put all columns in ascending order starting with `sender`, then `destination`, then `message`:

```
SELECT `sender`,`destination`,`message` FROM `chat` ORDER BY `sender`,`destination`,`message`
```

Output will be:

```
sender    destination    message
a         b              m1
a         b              m3
a         b              m4
b         a              m2
b         a              m5
```

---

Using this query to append grouped values into a single string with a newline as the "glue":

```
SELECT `sender`,`destination`,GROUP_CONCAT(`message` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `all_mess` FROM `chat` GROUP BY `sender`,`destination`
```

Output will be:

```
sender    destination    all_mess
a         b              m1
                         m3
                         m4
b         a              m2
                         m5
```

You may choose whatever separator you like in the [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

The backticks wrapping all of the column names and aliases are optional.

It will be up to you to decide how you wish to process and display the result set.

Based on the error statement in the question, it seems you are referencing database: `chat`, table: `chat`, column: `id` which was not included in your sql string of `SELECT * FROM chat GROUP BY sender` or anywhere in your question -- due to this inconsistency, I cannot help with that.

**If anyone would like to experiment with some queries using this sample table, you can use this** [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f7b07/1/0).

Hopefully this clears up any confusion for you and SO readers.